# What is the name of the timeline ("this") where objects are placed on the stage in Flash Pro 2015 HTML5 projects?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, easeljs, createjs

By this, I mean when you place the JavaScript code "this" directly on the timeline in Flash Pro CC 2015 (which uses CreateJS). Would you guys know the namespace of objects placed onto the stage via drag and drop from Flash's library?

"This" doesn't seem to be "stage", but a child of "stage", but trying "this.name" reveals null.

I ask because I have trouble referencing sibling displayObjects dragged onto the timeline from event listener functions. I can reference the objects themselves via event.currentTarget, but I have trouble referencing their siblings which I want to access also.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

By default, the exported root timeline can be accessed via the global `exportRoot` property, or as the first (and initially only) child of the stage.

`var root = this.stage.getChild(0);`